# Unable to add any indicator to panel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, indicator, panel

I was trying to add [this](https://github.com/mgedmin/indicator-netspeed) indicator. At first it worked well. I was changing some stuff in `dconf-editor` and now I have only the date, time, sound and power indicators. All the other indicators have vanished.

I had a working indicator-multiload and an indicator for [variety](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) before changing stuff in `dconf-editor`.

And now I'm not able to add anything to the panel. I tried installing an indicator but it doesn't work. The indicator installs fine but it doesn't appear in the panel.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what you changed in the config?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yeah. I tried to remove the 'input/type of keyboard indicator' and the 'bluetooth' indicator.

Answer (score 0):

### The hard way

Since you do not know what you have changed, you can reset the entries.

```
gsettings list-schemas | grep -i desktop.unity | xargs gsettings reset-recursively
gsettings list-schemas | grep -i com.canonical.Unity | xargs gsettings reset-recursively
```

Comment: I don't have 'desktop.unity' as well as 'com.canonical.Unity' under 'gsettings list-schemas'